# Как на слайдере вместо круглых кнопок управления создать текстовые?

Tags: jquery, slider

Для слайдера использовала вот этот код: http://webkab.ru/sozdaem-zamechatelnyj-slajder-na-jquery/
Но тут справа внизу для управления кружки. А мне необходимы не кружки, а нормальные кнопки с текстом разной ширины.
Подскажите, как это сделать ?

Comment: Чтобы было более понятно что мне необходимо, вот так выглядит сейчас сайт на этом слайдере. В середине белые квадраты навигации изначально были кружками со слайдера по ссылке в вопросе. Из кружков квадратами их сделать смогла, а вот как туда текст поместить не знаю (

Answer (score 3):

Откройте вашу таблицу стилей `s.css`, найдите там

```
.slider-controls .control-slide {
margin: 0;
display: inline-block;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
overflow: hidden;
text-indent: -9999px;
border: solid #ffffff;
background: url(radioBg.png) center bottom no-repeat;
}
```

Прежде всего уберите оттуда строку
`text-indent: -9999px;`
она задает отрицательный сдвиг текста на 9999px, поэтому текст не отображается.

Строку
`background: url(radioBg.png) center bottom no-repeat;`
тоже можно убрать, раз бэкграунд вы все равно не используете.

Потом можете отредактировать другие параметры так как вам нужно - изменить высоту, ширину, границу, цвет текста и т.д.

Если не нужна фиксированная ширина кнопок, уберите `width` и задайте `padding: 5px 15px;`

**UPD**  Да, элементы управления добавляются в скрипте.
Можно попробовать руками добавить в html код в <div class="slider"><div> блок с контролами
то есть, получить такую структуру

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-content">....</div>
    <div class="slider-controls"> 
        <span class="control-slide">цена</span>
         <span class="control-slide">контакты</span>
         <span class="control-slide">отзывы</span>
         <span class="control-slide">Место проведения</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

а в скрипте закомментировать в коде строки

```
/*var $adderSpan = '';
    $('.slide').each(function(index) {
            $adderSpan += '<span class = "control-slide">' + index + '</span>';
        });
    $('<div class ="slider-controls">' + $adderSpan +'</div>').appendTo('.slider');*/
```

возможно, после этого заработает как надо))

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! С css-то мне понятно итак было, но вы еще лучше расписали. А куда названия кнопок, сам текст вводить чтобы он отобразился на экране ? Вот в чем вопрос был.

Вот мне надо, допустим, такие 4 кнопки чтобы были: 
1.цена 2.контакты. 3.отзывы 4.Место проведения

В хтмле нет тегов между которыми можно вписать текст. Может быть надо в jquery скрипт что-то дописать ?

Comment: Посмотрите апдейт ответа